# Can I use KVC with primitive values?

Tags: objective-c, foundation

Example:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL running;
```

-valueForKey returns an id according to the documentation. But I slightly remember that KVC was so intelligent that it automatically wraps with NSNumber. Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. I thought about this a few days ago. :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.